# Changing $image to the actual image

Tags: php, image, email

**Code**:

```
    // Attach two files: an image and a zip archive
// - Each element contains: "file path", "file mime type"
$attach[] = array('$image', 'image/jpeg');

// Calls the sendMailAtt() to send mail, outputs message if the mail was accepted for delivery or not
if(sendMailAtt($to, $from, $subject, $message, $attach)) {
  echo 'The mail successfully sent';
}
```

If you look at the`$attach[]...` Line, the `array $image` does not work correctly.
If change it to something like: `image.jpg`, it works. But the simple `$image` (which is generated by uploading through Website) is 0 bytes when it sends by mail.

Is there anything i have to change in this line, so it uses the generated $image name in this array?

Comment: **Variables inside single quotes will not be intrepreted**

Comment: Are you using the native php `mail()` function or some other library to send email? take a look at this for normal `mail()` function to send attachment. http://webcheatsheet.com/php/send_email_text_html_attachment.php

Answer (score 1):

Read [strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php); You need to change it too,

```
$attach[] = array($image, 'image/jpeg');
```

Comment: So now it looks like it works as i want.
But, every Image is just 3 bytes :(

Answer (score 1):

if you add any code between `'` then it's not going to be interpreted the string inside it. if you do it between `"` then it's going to be interpreted.. that's the difference between `'` and `"` in php

And you should add it as

```
$attach[] = array($image, 'image/jpeg');
```

Comment: Yep, thank you. The Filename is now correct. But every Image is just 3 bytes :(.